# Maintain comma in data while changing delimiter

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that I need to change the delimiter to a pipe character, however I cannot find the right way to call csv writer to preserve commas in my data.

Example data below:

```
Record Type, Participant Full Name, Product Title
N,"Calvin Harris, The Weekend", Over Now
```

Current script:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filein,encoding='utf-8'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
writer = csv.writer(open('Detail_Test_Piped.csv', 'w',newline='',encoding='utf-8'), 
    delimiter='|',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Desired output:

```
Record Type|Participant Full Name|Product Title
N|Calvin Harris, The Weekend|Over Now
```

Current actual output:

```
Record Type|Participant Full Name|Product Title
N|Calvin Harris|The Weekend|Over Now
```

Screenshot of actual data file[image]

Comment: I think you just need to iteratively read from reader and use writer to write the data.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the output you describe when I call `writer.writerows(reader)`.

Comment: Same, I can't reproduce the issue. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: And this may be related: it looks like you're using `csv.reader(skipinitialspace=True)`, but that's not reflected in your code.

Comment: @Blckknght not sure how to provide you the data unfortunately. What I described is literally the two rows of data in the csv in which this issue occurs. I can edit the post and add a screenshot I suppose.

Comment: @Blckknght figured out my issue. I was being utterly brain dead, I kept opening this csv file in excel and it was automatically separating that comma. 100% my bad, appreciate the help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the cause of the issue was user error related to opening a file in the wrong program.

Comment: Excel is a dangerous thing to csv files. I've had a user clobber a large (64-bit) unsigned integer and mess up all the data contained therein.

Answer (score 2):

Why not leverage **pandas** for this task?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
df.to_csv('abc_piped.csv', sep='|')
```

[image]

Comment: The same issue occurs using this method.

Comment: after using **read_csv()** into a **dataframe** and then saving as a separate file **to_csv('', sep='|') ?** because as shown in the images it is working locally.

Comment: Does pandas `read_csv` handle quoted CSV entries? Also, you probably want to not include the index numbers in your `to_csv` call.

Comment: refer the parameter **quoting** = 3 # for ignoring quotes

Comment: @Agnij apologies, I was moving too quickly and opened in excel instead of notepad and it automatically separated on the comma. all good.

Comment: Just verified that the default read handles your input fine, and output with `df.to_csv('filename.csv', sep='|', index=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree that Pandas is a hugely useful package, I will go with what you have (with my changes):

```py
from csv import reader, writer, QUOTE_MINIMAL

with open(filein, encoding='utf-8') as in_fd,
     open('Detail_Test_Piped.csv', 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as out_fd:
    csv_read = reader(in_fd)  # Using defaults
    csv_write = writer(out_fd, delimiter='|', quotechar='"', quoting=QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csv_write.writerows(csv_read)
```

I don't know if it counts as an "advantage", but this works "out of the box" without having to install third-party packages.

Comment: Turns out this was all me being stupid, figured it all out.